# Extend JS web module Odoo PoS

Tags: javascript, module, odoo, extend

I want to extend the JS module **PosModel** in the models.js file (model is point_of_sale). This because I would like to add a field under:

```
models: [
     ...
     model:  'res.partner',
        fields: ['name','street',..,'MY_NEW_FIELD'],
```

I already added a new js file to my module under static > src > js > models_extend.js
And added this file to the xml template like so:

```
<template id="assets_backend" name="dewieuw assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/dewieuw/static/src/js/models_extend.js"></script>
        </xpath>
</template>
```

This is in my models_extend.js file:

```
function openerp_pos_models(instance, module){ //module is instance.point_of_sale
var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;
var _t = instance.web._t;

var round_di = instance.web.round_decimals;
var round_pr = instance.web.round_precision   

module.PosModel = module.PosModel.extend({
       "Here is the same is in the original file, except for the following line"
{
        model:  'res.partner',
        fields: ['name','street','city','state_id','country_id','vat','phone','zip','mobile','email','ean13','write_date','MY_NEW_FIELD'],
        domain: [['customer','=',true]],
        loaded: function(self,partners){
            self.partners = partners;
            self.db.add_partners(partners);
        },
    },
```

For some reason the new field is never added, I think this because he doesn't extend the module with my module? Any ideas pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS definition must include your custom module name to be loaded.

If you look at the [official docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html) you see that **your JS must declare your module scope**.

> In Odoo web, modules are declared as functions set on the global
>   openerp variable. The function's name must be the same as the addon
>   (in this case oepetstore) so the framework can find it, and
>   automatically initialize it.

So, if your module is named `oepetstore` you get something like this:

```
openerp.oepetstore = function(instance, local) {
```

In your case I guess it would be `openerp.dewieuw`.

Tip: do this and simply add a `console.log` or `alert('foo')` to make sure it gets loaded.

Comment: You are correct I changed this to openerp.dewieuw and also added a log above this line (module.PosModel = module.PosModel.extend({) and 1 underneath it. The first is printed the second one not..